# JavaScript: How to re-index multidimensional object after deleting a nested object?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, for-loop, object, indexing

I need to delete a nested object based on `index` and `i` and then re-index the object. I am using Vuejs, so this is in the methods. However, this code doesn't work the way I intended it to. The main issue is deleting `this.realTagFilters[0][0]` will also delete `this.realTagFilters[1][0]` and `this.realTagFilters[2][0]` and so on. It will also occasionally not correctly index the `index` or `i` but I have not found the cause of that issue yet. Overall, this code is pretty buggy and I could use some outside perspective on how to properly create this function.

*Edit: I am using an npm package for searchable multi-select selection lists that only allow objects to be passed to the options attribute.*

Here is the script:

```
export default {
props: {
  tag_filters: Object
},
data() {
   return {
     tagfilters: {
                0: {
                    0: {
                        code: {
                            code: 'Thank You Codes'
                        },
                        condition: {
                            condition: 'AND'
                        }
                    },

                }
            }
       }
}
computed: {
  realTagFilters() {
                if (Object.keys(this.tag_filters).length > 0 && typeof Object.keys(this.tag_filters) !== 'undefined') {
                    return this.tag_filters['filter'];
                } else {
                    return this.tagfilters;
                }
            }
},
method: {
       deleteFilter(index, i){
                delete this.realTagFilters[index][i];
                for(var property in this.realTagFilters) {
                    for (var p in this.realTagFilters[property]) {
                        if(property > index && p > i) {
                            property -= 1;
                            this.realTagFilters[property] = this.realTagFilters[property + 1];
                            delete this.realTagFilters[property + 1];
                            if(p > i) {
                                p -= 1;
                                this.realTagFilters[property][p] = this.realTagFilters[property][p + 1];
                                delete this.realTagFilters[property][p + 1];
                            }
                        }
                        else if (property == index && p > i) {
                            p -= 1;
                            this.realTagFilters[property][p] = this.realTagFilters[property][p + 1];
                            delete this.realTagFilters[property][p + 1];
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(Object.keys(this.realTagFilters[index]).length == 0) {
                    delete this.realTagFilters[index];
                }
                this.$forceUpdate();
            },
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you using objects instead of arrays? Note that `tagfilters[0]` is actually `tagfilters["0"]` because object keys are coerced to strings when added. If you used an array, `tagfilters[0]` would be `tagfilters[0]` and you could use array methods like `slice`, `filter`, etc. instead of the more cumbersome `delete`

Comment: I am using an npm package for searchable multi-select selection lists that only allow objects to be passed to the options attribute.

Comment: I suggest adding that restriction to the question so that others don't waste time suggesting changes to the object structure.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Vue's delete function in favor of javascript's delete keyword, so instead of doing `delete this.realTagFilters[index][i]` you'd do:

```
this.$delete(this.realTagFilters[index], i);
```

Another trick to let Vue know data has changed is to replace your object with a new object, like so:

```
// after you've done your operations:
this.realTagFilters = {...this.realTagFilters};
```

The last option is `this.$forceUpdate()` which you are already doing.